# Installing arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: software-installation, toolchain

I am following this guide:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Orange_Pi

I get errors on this command:`$ make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-`

Here is the errors:

```
make: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config.h
  UPD     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.autoconf:79: recipe for target 'u-boot.cfg' failed
make[1]: *** [u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
scripts/Makefile.autoconf:50: recipe for target 'include/autoconf.mk.dep' failed
  CFG     spl/u-boot.cfg
make[1]: *** [include/autoconf.mk.dep] Error 1
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.autoconf:82: recipe for target 'spl/u-boot.cfg' failed
make[1]: *** [spl/u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
```

My guess is because I don't have the  arm-none-eabi-gcc installed on my system but when I enter the command `sudo apt-get install arm-none-eabi-gcc` I get an error saying there is no such package.

Comment: You are following an Arch guide for a Debian-based system?

Comment: @Fox will it not work?

Comment: In general, no. Package managers, names, and availability vary between distros. Many system components also tend to differ, though that seems less of a concern in this case

Answer (score 15):

On Debian and derivatives, the package you’re looking for is `gcc-arm-none-eabi`:

```
apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

To find this out yourself in future, install `apt-file`, update your indexes and use it to search for commands:

```
apt install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
```